# Can code:blocks autocomplete text like xCode does?

Tags: c++, xcode, codeblocks

Sorry if this has been answered but I couldn't find any answers in searching.

I'm currently learning c++ and I'm using code:blocks on Windows 7.  I'm watching lynda.com tutorials and he is using xCode on a mac.  I notice when he types a command (like for) it will fill in the for loop form with placeholders for the information so he just has to enter the info and not type out all the syntax.  I've seen it do this with several different commands.

Is this common in most IDE's and is it something that code::blocks can do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Code::blocks should be able to do it and yes, it is common in mid-to-heavyweight IDEs. It used to be a plugin (keyword: "Code::Completion") but I'd expect it to have been borged into the main line by now.

Comment: I tried searching and looking under auto-completion settings, etc. but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  It's not under autocompletion or codecompletion.  It's under abbreviations.  You type the word (like for) and then click CTRL+J for it to complete the code.  It doesn't do it automatically as you type.

Thanks.